# Sound is not working in Asp.Net Timer

Tags: asp.net, ajax, audio, timer

This is working

```
<embed height="100" width="100" src="WindowsStartup.wav" />
```

But this is not working

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="4000">
    <embed height="100" width="100" src="WindowsStartup.wav" />
</asp:Timer>
```

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem source is you're nesting `embed` tag inside [`asp:Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398865.aspx) server control:

```
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="4000">
    <%-- This should be placed outside --%>
    <embed height="100" width="100" src="WindowsStartup.wav" />
</asp:Timer>
```

By inspecting rendered HTML output in browser dev tools, I found that the `embed` tag nested inside `Timer` control completely disappeared, leaving a hidden `span` tag with `id="Timer1"` where `asp:Timer` placed before:

```
<span id="Timer1" style="visibility:hidden;display:none;"></span>
```

To fix this issue, put `embed` tag outside the control markup, because anything inside server control markup may be reserved for [control properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4s70936s(v=vs.100).aspx) and possibly plain HTML tags inside it not rendered, with exception of certain properties which able to hold HTML templates (e.g. `ItemTemplate`).

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<embed height="100" width="100" src="WindowsStartup.wav" />
<asp:Timer ID="Timer1" runat="server" Interval="4000">
</asp:Timer>
```

This is rendered output of above markup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._initialize('ScriptManager1', 'form1', [], [], [], 90, '');
//]]>
</script>

<embed height="100" width="100" src="WindowsStartup.wav" />
<span id="Timer1" style="visibility:hidden;display:none;"></span>
```